# How to test upload file with mocha and chai?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, upload, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test my nodejs API with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/)/[Chai](http://chaijs.com/). I created a "test" folder which contain File.js with this code inside :

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

let fs = require('fs');

let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

var fileName = 'devJoke.png';

describe('/PUT file', () => {
    it('Should PUT a file', (done) => {
        let file = {
            fileName: "devJoke.png",
        }
        chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
            .put('/bucket/user2/files/')
            .set('secret_key', 'user2SecretKey')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
            .field('fileName', 'devJoke.png')
            .attach('files', "/Users/stagiaire/Downloads/devJoke.png")
            .send(file)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {

                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.be.a('object');
                    res.body.should.have.property('data').eql('File Uploaded')
                }
                done();
            })
    })
})
```

But when I am doing the command npm test, I got the error 
    `{ 
    Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:608:25)
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read',
    response: undefined }`

With PostMan I used headers with :

```
{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
{"secret_key":"user2SecretKey"}
```

And got this on body :

```
{"fileName":"devJoke.png"}
{"files": myFile}
```

It worked with PostMan and I tried to do the same with mocha/chai. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for creating form?

Comment: @shawon191, `.field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')`should do the job, right ?

Comment: Oh dear... This is my bad, I just forgot '/api' on my route.. This code works for people who wants to upload a file.